# When Were Morions Last Worn By Spanish Soldiers?

Tags: warfare, spain, armour

Around when were [morions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morion_(helmet)) last worn by Spanish soldiers, particularly in the Western Hemisphere?

[image]

I can't find much about this online.

I'm also wondering what they were replaced with at the time.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time sourcing it, but morions generally fell out of use in the second half of the 17th century.  The use would have officially been ended by the Ordinance of December 30, 1707 which established a French style uniform.  I may convert this into an answer if I can locate the source materials...

Comment: Thanks for helping on this question.  Juan Oñate is said to be "The Last Conquistador", and is depicted wearing a morion in 1598.  I suppose that tends to corroborate your statement.  Did the new French uniforms and helmets have an easy-to-search-for name?

Comment: Helmets were almost completely out of use at that time.  The French style headgear would have been [Bicornes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicorne) and (much less predominant until later) [Shakos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shako).  Metal helmets generally fell out of style in Europe after the 30 Years War. Part of the problem nailing down a definite answer is that prior to dissolving the [Tercios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercio) in 1704, there wasn't really a "standard" Spanish uniform.

Comment: Thanks again...  If there wasn't a standard Spanish uniform prior to 1704, I wonder if we could say that the morion was the one constant (or near-constant).